# Installing Ubuntu on a 128GB thumb drive

Tags: partitioning, usb, persistence

This is my first time using the forum and Ubuntu, so I apologize in advance if I do something wrong or don't understand.

Recently, I purchased a 128GB thumb drive that I wanted to install Ubuntu 14.04 on for research purposes. I currently have a 32GB thumb drive that my friend made for me a while back and now it's running out of room. I understand that if I want to use all 128GB, I would need to mess with the casper-rw file. After following multiple instructions on various threads, I can't seem to figure out how to increase the casper-rw file. This is what I have done so far:

- use universal usb installer to put ubuntu 14.04 on usb
- delete casper-rw
- use minitool partition wizard to partition a larger casper-rw file   (Gparted crashes if I try to do the partitions in 14.04, which apparently is a common problem when dealing with FAT32).
- reboot and choose to boot of off the 128GB drive
- obtain errors (black screen with blinking cursor sometimes even a "(initramfs) unable to find a live medium containing a live file system")

I would appreciate if someone can help me through this process because I just can't seem to understand what the problem is. Also, if you need more information about something please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: I would do a full install. I have a full install on my 16GB flash(BIOS boot) and a 64 GB flash drive (UEFI boot).  And I then can have data partition(s) for all my data. Full install to flash drive is just like any install, but you must use something else. And if UEFI boot desired, you must partition in advance. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu